# Understanding Leaflet 'Tileerror'

Tags: leaflet, wms

I currently have a faulty WMS layer that I am pulling from Geoserver. I am trying to understand why they are faulty by using Leaflets in-built 'tileerror' hook though the info that comes back doesn't seem to actually contain any info on what the error is.

Where in the tree should I be looking for some sort of error message / diagnostics?

[image]

Comment: Nowhere. Use your browser's [network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) instead.

Comment: Thank you - back to Geoserver.

Comment: This question might be worth expanding upon (other users might have similar issues). Perhaps @Jamie could answer themself, add a couple of screenshots from the network monitor, maybe a link to Leaflet's `tileerror` documentation and why https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#errors won't ever have enough info?

Comment: Would love to be able to add more context but this tracks back to an issue with Geoserver failing to render labelled WMS tiles. I was hoping that 'tileerror' may shed some light on it. Network monitor doesn't help as the calls to Geoserver are all successful - it's just that the rendered PNG's are blank.

Comment: Oh, I kinda expected Geoserver to return an error wrapped in some XML (that would be invisible to the image's `error` event)